# Does the Inspiring Leader feat just give everyone a bunch of Temp HP all the time?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, temporary-hit-points

One of my players took the Inspiring Leader feat, which allows them to do a 10 minute inspiring speech to grant the party some Temporary HP. This can be done again after a short rest.

Temporary HP lasts until a long rest, it's removed by damage, or it's replaced by another set of Temporary HP. So they should be able to refresh it after every short rest with a short inspiring chat.

I'm wondering if it's intended for this feat to (*essentially* if not technically) give everyone extra max HP. In a party of 4, on a character with a decent level + Charisma modifier, that would mean this feat is basically just worth several dozen extra HP total for the party as a whole, which is refreshed with every short rest. That seems like a lot!

**Is Inspiring Leader really a hefty HP boost for the party? Or is there some reason my players should not be able to take advantage of it at the tail end of every short rest they take?**

*Note: I'm not complaining - this group happens to have no healers, so them starting with a nice buffer is pretty helpful to me. I'm just wondering.*

Comment: keep in mind that temporary hit points don't stack so you can't combine them with things like *False Life* or *Armor of Agathys*

Comment: I'm confused, this question seems to use the terms 'max HP' and 'temp HP' interchangeably, while they are two drastically different things.  I know it's an old question, but it's currently on the front page and generating new answers, so fixing this would be useful.

Comment: @Theik I don't see it. The question mentions max HP once, and at that time it specifically says "essentially". I don't know that it's helpful to say "essentially extra max HP", but it definitely doesn't indicate any confusion about the difference.

Comment: How are you calculating "worth several dozen extra HP for the party"? Are you calculating that by adding together all of the individual temp HP values of each character that gets it, rather than indicating the amount of temp HP per person (which is the same for every character that receives them when the person with the feat inspires their allies)?

Comment: @V2Blast At level 6 with +4 Charisma and a party of 5, that's 50 HP. I consider 50 HP total as "several dozen extra HP for the party."

Comment: @MagRoader: So it's the first option I mentioned ("calculating that by adding together all of the individual temp HP values of each character that gets it"), then. ...Also, BTW, your question mentions a party of 4, not 5 :P

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The Temporary Hit Point total is equal to the "Inspired Leaders" Charisma Modifier + Level.

Therefore at first level, assuming a 15 in Charisma, they would spend 10 minutes listening to the Inspired Leaders speech for 3 Temporary Hit Points each for up to 6 allies.

To answer your question, yes it is a hit point boost to the party that increases as the character with the feat levels up, and improves their Charisma score modifier.

The only reason they should not be able to take advantage of it after every short rest is if they do not have the 10 minutes to listen to the speech or if giving the speech would attract unwanted attention.

Answer (score 17):

The [Inspiring Leader](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/inspiring-leader) feat states (PHB, p. 167):

> You can spend 10 minutes inspiring your companions, shoring up their resolve to fight. When you do so, choose up to six friendly creatures (which can include yourself) within 30 feet of you who can see or hear you and who can understand you. Each creature can gain temporary hit points equal to your level + your Charisma modifier. A creature can’t gain temporary hit points from this feat again until it has finished a short or long rest.

So yes, they can use this feat once per rest, so it is just a hefty HP boost.

Answer (score -1):

Giving the speech is not limited to once per short rest.  The person with this feat can babble on all day long passing out temp hp to 6 people every 10 minutes without taking a break.

Getting the temp hp can only happen once per short rest.  So if you got them, got in a fight or otherwise lost them, you would have to take a short rest before you could get replacement temp HP from this feat.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: This is correct, you could theoretically inspire 36 people per hour while awake, (assuming an eight hour rest and some breaks) a motivated individual could inspire upwards of 500 creatures.

Answer (score -2):

Also that ten minute line makes it basically a ritual.  Though non magical. And limited to once per short rest... Which most spells are not.

So it's not overpowered.

And a 2nd level Warlock can have False Life (self) at will, which provides significantly more potential Temp HP over a long day of battles. So it's certainly not more powerful than that.

Healer feat, provides an Extremely effective extremely affordable, technically non magical source of Healing.

You basically get a Field Medic for your team.

The Healer's Kits becomes its primary limitation  once per short rest per target, and turns stabilize into a Pseudo Goodberry.

Especially with no magical Healer in your party, Healer and Inspiring Leader would be great booms, and excellent Roleplay inspirations.

(both have limits upon them that make them difficult to abuse under extreme pressure)

All it takes is a chase that denies a peaceful short rest, and the recharge will be delayed.